# Is python-augeas missing a dependency on libpython2.7?

Tags: python

When I install `python-augeas` on a "minimal server" Ubuntu installation of 12.04 LTS, it throws the following import error when I try to use it:

```
# python

Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import augeas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/augeas.py", line 55, in <module>
    class Augeas(object):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/augeas.py", line 61, in Augeas
    for _v in ("%d.%d", "%d%d")])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/augeas.py", line 52, in _dlopen
    raise ImportError("Unable to import lib%s!" % args[0])
ImportError: Unable to import libpython2.7!
```

If I manually install `libpython2.7`, the problem goes away. Looking at the package info for `python-augeas`, there is no dependency listed for `libpython2.7`. Am I missing something or should this be in place? Should I file a bug report?